# Breaking complex condition to sub conditions - Python

Tags: python, parsing, conditional-statements, eval, brackets

I'm trying to parse a document filled with complex conditions to a logical dictionary.

eval() helps but i'm having a trouble when it comes to material conditional(->) (not supported in Python).

I'm sure there's an existing algorithm for breaking these conditions correctly and figuring out each sub condition the correct logical way (that's where i plan on changing "A->B" to "not(A) or B" before sending to eval())

I couldn't find anything useful while searching, hoping for insights.

Example:

Vars(in code):

```
x = True
y = False
m = True
z = False
c = 3
```

File.txt:

```
(x && y) || m
(x || m) && (y || z)
((x && y) -> m) || z 
(c in {3,5}) && z
```

Desired output:

```
dict = { '(x && y) || m': True, '(x || m) && (y || z)': False, etc.. }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do a similar exercise to this before, so here's what I would do

The first thing is to work out what operations cannot be resolved by eval. You mentioned the "->" operator, there also seems to be lists in braces rather than square brackets
e.g

```
c in {3,5}
```

For the "->" operator, you will need to grab the left and right operand and place them into "not (A) || B". The problem will be if A or B are bracketed expressions, which may be nested. For this you will need to loop through each char to the left (for A) and right (for B) and store the expression until you find the corresponding closing brackets. You can then resolve these, then substitute them in.